# lmerTest::lmer - model is not identifiable

Tags: r, lme4

I would like to know whether a plant development score depends on a plant treatment. So I have the following experimental setup:

- Treatment: "Control" or "Treated"
- Plantpart: the part of the plant that was followed. Either "Root", "Stem" or "Leaf".
- Score: the development score of the plant part. Explained variable, numeric (continuous).

I also have two factors treated as random errors:

- Block: 4 blocks (places where plants were grown)
- Biological_Replicate: each plant was used to gather the 3 plant parts (root, stem, leaf). Thus the scores of the plant parts of a given plant are not independent. There are 3 biological replicates per Block for treated and control plants.

I defined the variables then implemented the model:

```
library(lmerTest)
Score=Data$Score
Treatment=Data$Treatment
Biological_Replicate=as.factor(Data$Biological_Replicate)
Block=as.factor(Data$Block)
model<-lmer(Score~Treatment + (1|Biological_Replicate) + (1|Block), REML=FALSE)
```

Trying to retrieve the approximated p-value with `coef(summary(model))`
yielded the error:

```
Model is not identifiable...
summary from lme4 is returned
some computational error has occurred in lmerTest
```

The full data is below. The question is: what is wrong with the code, and/or the data?

```
Data<-structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Control", "Treated"), class = "factor"), 
    Plantpart = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Leaf", "Root", "Stem"), class = "factor"), 
    Block = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Biological_Replicate = c(1, 
    2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
    9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 12, 
    13, 14, 15, 13, 14, 15, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 16, 17, 18, 
    16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 19, 20, 21, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
    22, 23, 24, 22, 23, 24), Score = c(20628, 26610, 11410, 18755, 
    17366, 13228, 27011, 17558, 16512, 30945, 28606, 29092, 23262, 
    18306, 23034, 9627, 16193, 24391, 35197, 26092, 23789, 29900, 
    22649, 23548, 23868, 18495, 17204, 31750, 27496, 24687, 24115, 
    25911, 25076, 12472, 12267, 13120, 21580, 20697, 14854, 7190, 
    55734, 12194, 23853, 16762, 18322, 27582, 28056, 28497, 16156, 
    17680, 21789, 10137, 18122, 9786, 23866, 30878, 23101, 18104, 
    22276, 23694, 18534, 20743, 15460, 31997, 32559, 28969, 20408, 
    24503, 21395, 9925, 15407, 14717)), .Names = c("Treatment", 
"Plantpart", "Block", "Biological_Replicate", "Score"), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you should also provide a reproducible example. Without your data (or enough to replicate your error) it's hard to test your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How may I convert the data.frame so that one can use it in its own R?

Comment: using dput() is easier but I can guest one can use what you have included in your post. In model<-lmer(Score~Treatment + (1|Biological_Replicate) + (1|Block), REML=FALSE) you don't define your dataset

Comment: Indeed, I cut some code lines where I define the variables. I will add these lines in the main post (and look at dput()).

Comment: this thread will help you fix your problem https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2015q3/023962.html

Comment: I had read the answer provided but hoped to find a solution here. Do you suggest, too, that I contact the authors of lmerTest?

Comment: No I think it's related to your model. For example, Biological_Replicate (1 to 4) appears 4 times in each block! so for instance this work dfL <- dfL %>% filter(Plantpart == "Leaf"); model<-lmer(Score~Treatment + (1|Block), REML=FALSE, data=dfL); coef(summary(model))

Comment: Ok so that was what I missed. I tried `library(plyr)` and `count(Data,vars=c("Biological_Replicate","Block","Treatment"))` and I have a freq. of 3 in each case. Could you re-explain the problem?

Comment: Basically, you need to label appropriately your factors. You should look into the manual of the package lme4

Comment: dfL (being the name of your dataset); try this dfL$Biological_Replicate <- rep(1:36, 2); model<-lmer(Score~Treatment + (1|Biological_Replicate) + (1|Block), REML=FALSE, data=dfL); coef(summary(model))

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and efforts. I just looked at the code you propose (renaming the Biological Replicates); it does make `summary(model)` work but doesn't represent the structure of the experiment. The numbers of Biological_Replicate I currently have are much better at this game, though they create somehow a very nice bug.

Comment: @Thomas, have you had any luck addressing this problem?  I am getting similar errors from lmerTest and would love to know how you dealt with them.